# Assign dynamic weight to group of variables

Tags: ordered-logit

I am building a ordinal logistic regression model, with 10 independent categorical variables (*X1 .... X10*). I would like to split the variables into groups of importance and assign 60% weight to group of variables (let's say *X5, X6, X7*) and the rest with 40%.

Is this a post regression treatment on co-efficients or a case of data preparation before executing the regression? Appricate if there is any information on methods addressing this.